# Node.js is there a way to send an array within a JSON response?

Tags: arrays, node.js, ajax

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to send an array in a JSON response in an node.js 
I have attached dataPoints1, dataPoints2 and dataPoints3 within the response which they are arrays. But when it is received from a Ajax request, it just becomes a string that is [object object],[object object]

```
responsearray = '{"result":{"System":"Ready","Allcompleted":"completed","dataPoints1":"'+dataPoints1+'","dataPoints2":"'+dataPoints2+'","dataPoints3":"'+dataPoints3+'"}}';
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.type('application/json');
    res.send(responsearray);
```

Is there a way that i can send an array within an JSON string from an ajax call then turn that back into an array? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.send` method accepts JavaScript object as an argument. You don't need to build a string.

Try with:

```
var responsearray = {
  result: {
    System: "Ready",
    Allcompleted: "completed",
    dataPoints1: dataPoints1,
    dataPoints2: dataPoints2,
    dataPoints3: dataPoints3
  }
};

/// ...

res.send(responsearray);
```

ref.: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Comment: I think it works, thanks! Need to reconfirm tomorrow morning, but looks like its working.